# Delegate for Limitation of characters in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I have a form which have Delegate for field to limit to enter 4 digits in a field.Now i have another field i want to use another limitation on different field in same form which can limit the field to enter only seven values.How can i use two delegate in same form, if i use them they show error that its twice used. This is the delegate which i have use for the first field.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

{

}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Delegates, rather look into one delegate doing everything...

You can use an if inside the delegate, differentiating between the textfields:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == textField1)
    {
        if(range.length + range.location > 4)
        {
            return NO;
        }

        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        return newLength <= 4;     
    }

    if (textField == textField2)
    {
        if(range.length + range.location > 7)
        {
            return NO;
        }

        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        return newLength <= 7;          
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: can u explain how can i make limitation in it? @Burnie777

Comment: im getting an error , i have edited my question and add screenshots, please check that out. @Burnie777

Comment: @umer, pleasure

Answer (score 1):

To identify different textfield in same controller you can give tag to them. Now lets take an example you have two textfield and you give them tag as 100 and 200 respectively. Now you need to restrict the character that a user can enter to 4, in first textfield whose tag is 100, and 10 in second textfield whose tag is 200. So your code will go like follows:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    //To make sure no crashes occurs
    if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSUInteger textLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

    if (textField.tag == 100) {

        return textLength <= 4;

    }else if(textField.tag == 200){

        return textLength <= 10;

    }else{

        //Other textfields except the one with tag 100 and 200 would have no limits
        return YES;
    }

}
```

I have demonstrated this example with an IF condition you can use Switch case or whatever you want to apply.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Bro its not working , i have used tags but both fields are taking only 4 digits. @IOS_MIB

Comment: This is the standard way of doing this. You might not have given tag properly to your textfields. Try again by properly giving tags to your textfields.